# How to render a semi transparant MTKView on macOS?

Tags: macos, alpha, metal

I've got a Metal shader with an output of alpha 0.5 running fine on **iOS**, showing the underlying views. Tho on **macOS** is's not working. There's a black background, even tho the background of the **MTKView**'s layer is set to clear..

I've noted that the **MTKView**'s `.isOpaque` property is not settable on macOS, tho not sure if that is the problem as it's already set to `false`.

Is there another way to achieve transparacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `isOpaque` property of the `CAMetalLayer` to false. There's a comment in the CAMetalLayer.h header file (Objective-C) that says:

> ```
> /* Note: The default value of the `opaque' property for CAMetalLayer
>  * instances is true. */
> ```

Comment: It worked! I'm porting an iOS framework to macOS (pre UIKit on Mac), not used to these properties being accessed though the layer and not the view. Thanks